# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'FlashSaleMapping' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
foreach (var objUser in responseToken.SpecificUsers.SpecificUsers)
{
    flashObj.FlashSaleId = flashSalesObj.Id;
    flashObj.MappingId = Convert.ToInt32(objUser);
    flashObj.type = "Users";
    flashObj.CreatedOnUTC = DateTime.Now;

    _context.FlashSaleMapping.Add(flashObj);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I used this code first loop successfully saved when start; second time around, I get the error mentioned in the title.

Comment: Your code is trying to save the same object over and over. Create *new* objects and *don't* call `SaveChanges` inside the loop. Use it only once, when you want to save *all* changes back to the database. That's how all ORMs work - changes are maintained locally and saved/committed in a single operation at the end. If you want to rollback changes, well,no changes have been made yet so you can just discard the context. You don't even need a transaction

Comment: Using EF propertly can result in orders of magnitude better performance - just 1 batched insert instead of 100 individual INSERTS and network roundtrips. No blocking due to long-lived transactions either

Answer (score 0):

You must create an new object in every loop

**_context.SaveChanges();** generate an new id in the first loop but keep this id for all other loop. In addition to that this foreach loop add several time the same object.

```cs
foreach (var objUser in responseToken.SpecificUsers.SpecificUsers)
                    {
                        var newFlashSaleMapping = new FlashSaleMapping();
                        newFlashSaleMapping.FlashSaleId = flashSalesObj.Id;
                        newFlashSaleMapping.MappingId = Convert.ToInt32(objUser);
                        newFlashSaleMapping.type = "Users";
                        newFlashSaleMapping.CreatedOnUTC = DateTime.Now;
                        _context.FlashSaleMapping.Add(newFlashSaleMapping);

                    }
_context.SaveChanges(); //bulk sav
```

```
//LINQ version
var newFlashSaleMappings = responseToken.SpecificUsers.SpecificUsers.Select((flashSalesObj) = >
                    new FlashSaleMapping() {
                        FlashSaleId = flashSalesObj.Id,
                        MappingId = Convert.ToInt32(objUser),
                        type = "Users",
                        CreatedOnUTC = DateTime.Now                      
                    });
_context.FlashSaleMapping.AddRange(newFlashSaleMapping);
_context.FlashSaleMapping.SaveChanges();
```